# Schedule Task LastRun is always returning same time as DateTime.Now, causing issues with task time window checking

Tags: scheduled-tasks, scheduler-job

I have a scheduled task that I recently realized isn't working properly. The Sitecore task is running, but in the code I have  time check to make sure that it only runs within a one-hour window (2am to 3am), and only if it hasn't already run in that window:

```
    protected virtual bool IsDue(ScheduleItem scheduleItem)
    {
        DateTime timeBegin;
        DateTime timeEnd;

        DateTime.TryParse("02:00:00", out timeBegin);
        DateTime.TryParse("03:00:00", out timeEnd);

        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info("IsDue timeBegin: " + timeBegin.ToString(), this);
        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info("IsDue timeEnd: " + timeEnd.ToString(), this);
        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info("IsDue now: " + DateTime.Now.ToString(), this);
        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info("IsDue Last Ran: " + scheduleItem.LastRun.ToString(), this);

        return (CheckTime(DateTime.Now, timeBegin, timeEnd) && !CheckTime(scheduleItem.LastRun, timeBegin, timeEnd));
    }

    private bool CheckTime(DateTime time, DateTime after, DateTime before)
    {
        return ((time >= after) && (time <= before));
    }
```

I discovered through the logging that my code isn't running because it always returns `IsDue = false`, because *scheduleItem.LastRun is always equal to DateTime.Now*. Here's a sample from my logs:

```
INFO IsDue timeBegin: 21.10.2021 02:00:00
INFO IsDue timeEnd: 21.10.2021 03:00:00
INFO IsDue now: 21.10.2021 02:04:18
INFO IsDue Last Ran: 21.10.2021 02:04:18
INFO Ended: Trial Import Schedule
INFO Trial Import Job not due at this time
```

Every instance in the logs is like this, where DateTime.Now is the exact same value as scheduleItem.LastRan. As a result my code never runs because it always thinks that the task has already run within the time window.

Comment: I know this is not super helpful, but this kind of thing is why I never use the Sitecore Task scheduler. Use Akshay's SiteCron module, it is so much more accurate and reliable. So not a fix for your code, but maybe an alternative to get you running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior occurs if your scheduled task is set to run asynchronously. To avoid this behavior, be sure that the `Async` field of your scheduled task item is not checked:

[image]